# Import fails for Gaussian calculation output file

Tags: import, chemistry, format

Mathematica seems to import Gaussian16 calculation output files usually without any troubles. However, with the recent 13.3.0 version, I noticed that some calculation output files are not imported, and no reason is provided apart from

`Message[Import::fmterr, "GaussianLog"]`

For the same system composition, there are other calculation files that work correctly, and even this particular file can be imported as text data. The calculation did not fail, and the output file has all the elements of a successful output.

However, I am interested in importing it directly as a Molecule object – which seems to be the default action on GaussianLog files. The file is provided [here](https://ufile.io/xj3vrqce).

My version is: 13.3.0 for Linux x86 (64-bit) (June 3, 2023)

Comment: this particular file can't be opened by any version of mathematica. Please report to Wolfram technical support and hopefully this can be fixed in a future version.

Comment: I can't get Avogadro to open this particular file either, when you file a report be sure to include other examples of files that fail to import.

Comment: GaussView will open this file correctly and show a summary of results. That happens for all successful calculations. I did not check Avogadro – thanks for the tip. I will file a technical support ticket.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Until this is fixed, the following function should work to import the molecule geometry from a Gaussian output file.  It does not work with charged fragments, nor does it import any other type of data.

```
readGaussianStandardOrientation[file_] := Enclose @ Module[
  {stream, line, xyz},
  stream = Confirm @ OpenRead @ file;
  line = "";
  (* skip ahead to the geometry *)
  While[
    And[StringQ[line],
      UnsameQ[StringTrim @ line, "Standard orientation:"]
    ],
    line = ReadLine @ stream
  ];
  (* the next lines are table headings *)
  Do[ReadLine @ stream, 4];
  line = ReadLine @ stream;
  xyz = CreateDataStructure @ "DynamicArray";
  While[StringQ[line] && StringFreeQ[line, "---"],
    (* after the last coordinate line is a line of all - characters *)
    xyz["Append", line];
    line = ReadLine @ stream
  ];
  Close @ stream;
  xyz = StringRiffle[
    StringReplace[Normal @ xyz,
      RuleDelayed[
        StringExpression[StartOfString,
          Whitespace, NumberString, Whitespace, n:NumberString, Whitespace, NumberString,
          Whitespace, rest__, EndOfLine
        ],
        StringJoin[Confirm @ PacletSymbol["Chemistry", "FromAtomicNumber"] @ ToExpression @ n, "   ", rest]
      ]
    ],
    "\n"
  ];
  ImportString[xyz, "XYZ"]
]
```

When run on your input file we get this cluster

[image]

Comment: Great, thanks a lot!